# sfWidgetFormI18nDateTime with more years

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I'm using sfWidgetFormI18nDateTime in a form, and I have to add more years to it (back in time). For example 2007, 2006, 2005 etc.

sfWidgetFormI18nDate widget does support the "years" attribute, but DateTime doesn't.

Here's my code:

```
$this->widgetSchema['created_at'] = new sfWidgetFormI18nDateTime(array('culture' => 'hu'));
$this->validatorSchema['created_at'] = new sfValidatorDateTime(array('required' => false));
```

I need something like this:

```
$this->widgetSchema['created_at'] = new sfWidgetFormI18nDateTime(array('culture' => 'hu', 'years' => metWidgetTools::getYears()));
$this->validatorSchema['created_at'] = new sfValidatorDateTime(array('required' => false, 'years' => metWidgetTools::getYears()));
```

Is there a way that I can go around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your widget schema should looks something like this

```
$years = range(2000, date('Y')); // from to 2000 to current year
$this->widgetSchema['created_at'] = new sfWidgetFormI18nDateTime(array(
    'culture' => 'hu',
    'date' => array(
        'years' => array_combine($years, $years)
    )
));
```